# Capturing a pixel surface on mouse selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, mouseevent

I'm starting a project on the web, where i need to calculate number of pixels selected by mouse. At my knowledge currently I would start capturing at mouseDown event and end at mouseUp event (from when I'm starting to drag until the end). Now I need to capture this width and height in pixels, so that I can get the surface of an area. Is that possible with jQuery or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JQuery offset method http://api.jquery.com/offset/.

On mouse down get the top and left offset and save them and then do the same on mouse up. Subtract the starting top from the ending top and the starting left from the ending left and then take the absolute value of both and you have the size of the selected area.